# Spotify API Returns public: False for All Playlists Despite Being Public

Tags: python, rest, spotify, spotipy, data-retrieval

I am using the Spotify API through the Spotipy library in Python to check the public status of various playlists. However, I consistently receive `public: False` for all playlists, despite them being publicly accessible and owned by me.

#### Problem

The issue occurs when fetching playlist details using the Spotipy library. Every playlist, regardless of its actual status, returns with `public: False`.

#### Approach

- Authentication via OAuth with the `playlist-read-private` scope.
- The script successfully retrieves other details of the playlists.
- All tested playlists are owned by my account.

#### Code Example

```py
import os
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

# OAuth authentication setup
auth_manager = SpotifyOAuth(
    client_id=os.getenv("SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID"),
    client_secret=os.getenv("SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET"),
    redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1:5000/callback',
    scope='playlist-read-private'
)
code = auth_manager.parse_response_code(httpd.path)
token_info = auth_manager.get_access_token(code, as_dict=False)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)

# Fetching playlist details
playlist_details = sp.playlist(playlist_url)
```

## Question

Why does the Spotify API return public: False for playlists that are publicly accessible? Is there an issue with the scopes, or am I missing something in my implementation?

Python version: 3.9.13

Comment: They only will return true if they are publicly displayed on someone's profile.